# How to check realm for android data existence?

Tags: android, realm

how do I check whether certain value is exist or not in my realm database based on this code below?

```
realm.where(User.class).equalTo("cardId", cardId).findFirst()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can perform null check.

```
User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("cardId", cardId).findFirst();

if (user != null) {
    // Exists
} else {
    // Not exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I'm looking for. I'm fairly new to Realm though.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I have to set master password for very first time in my app just after installation and after ward just verify it. For that I have to check realm database whether such object exists if yes then just verify else set master pass password. As realm is nosql database so we have to check for object existence instead table. 
Thus,

```
CustomObject custom = realm.where(CustomObject.class).findfirst();

if(custom == null){
//set master password
} else {
//verify master password
}
```

works for me!!